# Can someone explain me how to make a program in pascal that will add every second number until sum is 100?

Tags: pascal

I have tried doing this but it doesn't seem to work.
It only works when I enter number 55 3 times but won't work in any other case.

```
var
   x: array[1..100] of integer;
   i, suma: integer;
begin
   suma := 0;
   repeat 
      readln(x[i]);
      for i := 1 to 100 do 
      begin
         if i mod 2 = 0 then suma := suma + x[i];
      end;
   until suma >= 100;
end.
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen in the line `readln(x[i]);`? You did not even initialize i. I would suggest to do some [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: For some reason it still lets me enter the numbers, if I put it inside the loop under it, it loops to infinity

Comment: You need to learn how to debug your code. If your environment does not support debugging (step by step execution and watching variable values), you can add sone 'writeln(<variable>);` in your code, with <variable> being the variable you're interested in. As a start, you did not initialize `i` and `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at what your code is doing.

You repeat until `suma` is greater than or equal to `100`. This is good. Inside this you read into `x[i]` but `i` has not been initialized.

Assuming this were working, you then loop 100 times, adding uninitialized members of your array to `suma`.

This is mostly unnecessary. An array certainly is.

We need to loop on repeat until the sum is greater than or equal to 100. Within this loop, we need to read in numbers, and we need to keep track of whether or not the current loop is even or odd.

```
program Test;
var
  user_input: integer;
  sum: integer = 0;
  i: integer = 0;

begin
  repeat
    read(user_input);

    if i mod 2 = 0 then
      sum := sum + user_input;

    i := i + 1;
  until sum >= 100;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I think I finally made a program that will do as I asked in the question.

```
var
   x: integer;
   i, suma: integer;
begin
   suma := 0;
   i := 1;
   repeat 
      readln(x);
      if i mod 2 = 0 then suma := suma + x;
      i := i + 1;
   until suma >= 100;
end.
```